# Given $Imf(x + iy) = x^2 − y^2.$, find $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such that for $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$,  $$Imf(x + iy) = x^2 − y^2.$$

Find $f.$

Im really not sure how to approach this question so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If It is holomorphic, it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  That might be a way to relate the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 2):

$f (x+iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$

If f is holomporhic

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$

$v = (x^2-y^2)\\
\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = -2y\\
\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = -2x$

$u = -2xy+c$

Or since polynomials are always holomorphic.

$f(z) = i z^2+c$

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy Riemann gives $\partial Im f/\partial y =\partial Ref/\partial x$ and
$\partial Imf/\partial x=-\partial Ref/\partial y$. This implies that

$\partial Ref/\partial x= -2y$ and $\partial Ref/\partial y=-2x$ we deduce $Re(f)=-2yx+c$.